# Processing several files one-by-one separately by Spark

Tags: apache-spark, parallel-processing

I need help with implementation one workflow with Apache Spark. My task is in next:

1. I have several CSV files as source data. Note: these files could has different layout
2. I have metadata with info how I need parse each file (this is not problem)
3. Main goal: result is source file with several additional columns. I have to update each source file without joining to one output range. For example: source 10 files -> 10 result files and each result file have data only from corresponding source file.

As I know Spark can open many files by mask:

```
var source = sc.textFile("/source/data*.gz");
```

But in this case I can't recognize which line of a file. If I get list of source files and try to process by following scenario:

```
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(...);
List<String> files = new ArrayList() //list of source files full name's
for(String f : files)
{
   JavaRDD<String> data = sc.textFile(f);
   //process this file with Spark
   outRdd.coalesce(1, true).saveAsTextFile(f + "_out"); 
}
```

But in this case I will processed all files in sequential mode.

**My question is next**: how I can processed many files in parallel mode?. For example: one file - one executor?

Thank very much for help me!

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps

1. Use sparkcontext.wholeTextFiles("/path/to/folder/containing/all/files")
2. The above returns an RDD where key is the path of the file, and value is the content of the file
3. rdd.map(lambda x:x[1]) - this give you an rdd with only file contents
4. rdd.map(lambda x: customeFunctionToProcessFileContent(x))
5. since map function works in parallel, any operations you do, would be faster and not sequential - as long as your tasks don't depend on each other, which is the main criteria for parallelism

The above works with default partition though. So you might not get input files count equal to output file count(as output is number of partitions).

You can re-partition the RDD based on count or any other unique value based on your data, so you end up with output files count equal to input count. This approach will have only parallelism but will not have the performance achieved with optimal number of partitions

Comment: Hi Ramzy, Thank for your answer, but I have another query. Method `sparkcontext.wholeTextFiles("/path/to/folder/containing/all/files")` open and read file in memory. As I know most of source files will have ~1-3 million lines but several files can has size up to 2-3 GB. This will works without any memory errors?

Comment: When you use, sc.textFile or sc.wholeTextFiles, the computation is not started yet. It is only when you perform any action the processing starts, and that is based on the default partitions the data set is being divided. You can get the number of partitions by yourRDD.partitions.length and customize as per your need, and also get the yourRDD.count() to get the actual RDD size.

Comment: @Ramzy, wholeTextFiles will create RDD with key of path and value of whole context of file. If some files are 2-3GB there will be clearly a problem(depends on executor memory, but GBs for 1 partition is too much in any case)

Answer (score 0):

You can open regular java fixed size thread pool(say 10 threads) and submit spark job your saveAsTextFile from Callable/Runnable.
This will submit 10 parallel jobs, and if you have enough resources in your spark cluster - they will be executed in parallel.
Something like following

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;

import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        final JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(...);
        List<String> files = new ArrayList<>(); //list of source files full name's
        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        List<Future<?>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
        for(final String f : files)
        {
            Future<?> fut = pool.submit(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    JavaRDD<String> data = sc.textFile(f);
                    //process this file with Spark
                    outRdd.coalesce(1, true).saveAsTextFile(f + "_out"); 

                }
            });
            futures.add(fut);

        }
        //waiting for all tasks
        for (Future<?> fut : futures) {
            fut.get();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think that this make sense. I will try this approach.

Comment: May I know how are the tasks defined for a thread and how are they collected and presented. And with this approach, would the parallelism of 10 is achieved? The applications Mapreduce and spark are for parallel processing. Please revisit the basics may be and see if they fit the requirement

Comment: @Yustas, I've added some code that wraps your task in Runnable

Comment: @Ramzy, see and try yourself. This approach working. If you defining spark action from different threads in driver - all those are converted to separate parallel jobs. Parallelilsm will be 10 * number of partitions in each file.

Comment: It is definitely doable. But in the case of threads, how do you set the limits of which files to process and then get the results from them? All these stuff is handled by spark/mapreduce when used properly. If the usage of threads fits your requirement, you are welcome to proceed. I am just trying to understand the process. Thank you

Comment: This approach is still using spark and not implementing adhoc solution using threads. It just submits several spark jobs in parallel

Comment: Hi This code not works. Failed with exception: `Exception in thread "pool-13-thread-1" Exception in thread "pool-13-thread-2" java.lang.Error: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1151)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)`